# Grabbing value from column and show everything from that row depending if value is correct (LINQ - c# web API)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
[ID] [5TypeOfIntegers] [TEXT] [name ID]
```

5TypeOfIntegers has 5 integers. ( 1 - 5).

I wanna grab 2 values from my 5 types(value 2 and 4), and grab the data if name ID match, the other 3 values (values 1,3 and 5) I wanna grab that data if the name ID does not match.

Example:

```
[ID] [5TypeOfIntegers] [TEXT] [nameID]  = User logged is 1. 
 0         2             bla     1         - GRAB DATA (Type is correct and user is correct))
 1         3             bla     1         - DONT GRAB DATA (Type is wrong and user is correct)
 2         3             bla     2         - GRAB DATA (Different ID from the person logged in, Type is correct)
```

My idea of LINQ code is something like:

```
db.Where(e => e.nameID == 1).Select( e => e.5TypeOfIntegers == 2 && e.5TypeOfIntegers == 4)
```

But after that I'm kinda lost and that doesn't even work. :(

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, to be clear, you have the Column `5TypeOfIntegers`. You want to rows with 2 and 4 if the NameId matches the NameID you supply, and then grab rows with 1, 3, and 5 when the NameID does not match what you supply. In that case, you could do something like (where the nameID you pass in is nameIdVar `db.Table.Where(e => (e.5TypeOfInterger in (2, 4) && e.nameID = nameIdVar) || (e.5TypeOfInterger in (1,3,5) && e.nameID != nameIdVar)`

Comment: What @chadk said is literally what you asked for not IMO either the question is unclear or it's https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem, can you please elaborate on what is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

So, in other words you want "not(type 1,3,5 and nameId = currentlyloggedin)"

```
var types = new[]{1,3,5};
context.Whatever.Where(x => !(types.Contains(x.Type) && x.UserId == currentlyLoggedInUserId));
```